# DeadObjectException when trying to use Places SDK

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I've been trying to use the Places SDK for Android but encounter problems whenever trying to access the current place using PlaceDetectionClient.getCurrentPlace(). I have added an unrestricted API key to the manifest file and enabled the Places SDK in the Google Console. My code is below, and within a Service:

```
try {
    mPlaceDetectionClient.getCurrentPlace(null)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse likelyPlaces) {
            if (likelyPlaces != null && likelyPlaces.getCount() > 0) {
                int bestIndex = 0;
                float bestLikelihood = likelyPlaces.get(0).getLikelihood();
                for (int i = 1; i < likelyPlaces.getCount(); i++) {
                    if (likelyPlaces.get(i).getLikelihood() > bestLikelihood) {
                        bestIndex = i;
                    }
                }
                PlaceManager.setPlace(likelyPlaces.get(bestIndex).getPlace());
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "place was null!");
            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
            stopSelf();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "place failure!" + e);
            stopSelf();
        }
    });
} catch (SecurityException se) {
    Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException when getting place");
    stopSelf();
}
```

The specific error I am getting is as follows, and repeats every five seconds for two minutes:

```
11-08 13:41:33.426 3398-3429/domain.temp.wearapp E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 284)
11-08 13:41:33.432 3398-3429/domain.temp.wearapp W/GmsClient: IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed
    android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:748)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.IGmsServiceBroker$Stub$zza.getService(Unknown Source:13)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(Unknown Source:244)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabo.run(Unknown Source:8)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

After two minutes, it stops attempting to retry and gives the following exception in the onFailure call:

```
11-08 13:41:35.429 3398-3398/domain.temp.wearapp E/PlaceService: place failure!com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: INTERNAL_ERROR
```

I've spent hours trying to solve this by searching online and tweaking various things (it was originally an IntentService), but haven't had any luck. I'd really appreciate any help!